# Save results for each file of a list of files looping through a factor variable in R. Vector does not update

Tags: list, loops, vector, levels

I am using a list of files, and I am trying to create a data frame that contains: for each sample, the percentage of two particular "GT" types by the levels of another factor variable called "chr" (with 1 to 24 levels).

It would have to look like this:

The problem I keep getting is that the vector never gets updated for the ith sample, it only keeps the first vector created. And then I am not sure how to save that updated vector on my data frame (df).

```
vector_chr <- vector();
for (i in seq_along(list_files)) {
  GT <- list_files[[i]][,9]
  chr <- list_files[[i]][,3]
  GT$chr <- chr$chr # creating one df with both GT and chr
  for (j in unique(GT$chr)){
    dat_list = split(GT, GT$chr)           # split data frames by chr (1 to 24)
    table <- table(dat_list[[j]][,1])      # take GT and make a table
    sum <- sum(table[3:4])                 # sum GTs 3 and 4
    perc <- sum/nrow(GT)
    vector_chr <- c(vector_chr,perc)       # assign the 24 percentages to a vector
    }
  df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 25, nrow = length(files)))
  x <- c("Sample", "chr1", "chr2", "chr3",
         "chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr10",
         "chr11", "chr12","chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16",
         "chr17", "chr18", "chr19", "chr20", "chr21", "chr22",
         "chrX", "chrXY")
  colnames(df) <- x
  df$Sample <- names(list_files)
  df[i,2:25] <- vector_chr                # assign the 24 percentages for EACH sample 
}
```

Comment: Put `vector_chr <- vector()` inside the `for` loop instead of defining it outside. Also, You can improve the coding a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, and it works but it only saves the output for the last updated vector.

Comment: In the rows of `df`, all the outputs should be saved, right?